# Android SDK Manager doesn't show Android SDK Platform_tools

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I want to run my app in Android Studio. But I can't create virtual device. I see this massage:
"No System image available. Are you connected to the internet?"
And I'm connecting to the internet.
Problem is from my Android SDK Manager. It should be like this:

android sdk manager
[image: android sdk manager]

But for me is like this:
[image: my android sdk manager]

I should install Android SDK Platform_tools but there is not in list.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: install Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/

Comment: I have installed it.

Comment: It solved by setting HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You are using from an old version of Android Studio and It is a feature that gone deprecated in version 2.3! (Standalone SDK Manager)

Download latest version from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads)
and use `Preferences > Android Sdk` to download Sdk and platform-tools etc.

[image]